# Swift: Is it possible to generate viewControllers dynamically through code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, tvos

I am receiving this through in an API request response:

```
"menus": {
    1 =     {
        id = 1;
        label = Accueil;
        maxNumberPerPage = 20;
    };
    2 =     {
        id = 2;
        label = "Mes favoris";
        maxNumberPerPage = 20;
    };
    3 =     {
        id = 3;
        label = "Les s\U00e9lections";
        maxNumberPerPage = 20;
    };
    4 =     {
        id = 4;
        label = "Acc\U00e8s illimit\U00e9";
        maxNumberPerPage = 20;
    };
},
```

Depending on the number of elements in this `menu` object, I will generate a different ViewController, which will contain a different UI and a different logic.
The title of these ViewControllers, will be the property `label` from the `menu` object.
The user will be able to navigate through these viewControllers thanks to a tabBar.
So this is the result so far:
[image]
This is the function that creates the TabBar:

```
   func createTabBarController() {
        let menus = CMSessionManager.sharedInstance.menus!
        var controllerArray : Array<UIViewController> = []
        for (key,menuInfo) in menus {
            if let menuInfoDetails = menuInfo as? [String: Any] {
                                        let newViewController = UIViewController()
                                        newViewController.title = menuInfoDetails["label"] as! String
                                        controllerArray.append(newViewController)
            }
        }
        tabBarCnt.viewControllers = controllerArray.map{ UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: $0)}
        self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)
    }
```

So here I am generating each viewController in the same tabBarController code:

```
  let newViewController = UIViewController()
  newViewController.title = menuInfoDetails["label"]
```

What I want is:
Each viewController to be represented with a separate **label_ViewController.swift** file.
So this is my problem:
I don't know how many items there will be in the `menu` object. Therefore, I don't know how many **UIViewController** files should I create in advance.
I don't really see anyway to solve this issue.
So the question is:
Is there any way to solve this problem? Or should I do everything programmatically?

**NOTE:** I need each item to be associated with a **UIViewController** file. This is because the viewController will be present in the storyboard "physically" and therefore each file will represent the logic of each view.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want an app that update the Xcode project (create Swift code and update storyboards) itself based on an API response?

Comment: That or if there's another solution to my problem then it's welcome.

Comment: Then no, it's not possible. The only thing I can think of to achieve that is to have the same UIViewController that can render all the possible layouts based on what the API can send you.

Comment: If you actually create a new Swift file, then you will need to rebuild your app before it can use the new view controller.  Also, if you create a completely new view controller file, where does its logic come from?

Comment: @rraphael That makes sense. And depending on the "label" a different logic will be executed inside the viewController. However, this doesn't feel like an optimal solution. As different logics of different views will be contained in the same file.

Comment: Not necessary on the same file. This is a really hard task you are trying to achieve (adapting almost your whole application dynamically from an API response). This will require a lot of architectural thinking and design if you want to project to be maintainable tho. And at this point, you should not be looking for the optimal solution but a solution that can work (you should build a Proof of Concept), and keep improving it from this point.